# Monitoring Locks with Java Flight Recorder and Java Mission Control

Tags: java, java-8, jmc, jfr, java-mission-control

## What I want to do

I have a Java program which I am trying to improve. I suspect synchronized blocks within the code to hurt performance but I would like to make sure this is my problem before touching my code.

## How I went on about it

To check if synchronized blocks are indeed the issue, I recorded the execution of my program on a test server with Flight Recorder, downloaded the created `jfr` file on my desktop and opened it with Java Mission Control. However the `Lock Instances` page in `Java Application` does not show anything. The only clue I get is a message in the Results view which reads:

> The Java Blocking rule requires event(s) to be available from the following event types: com.oracle.jdk.JavaMonitorEnter

I am therefore assuming there must be some kind of option to activate along with the flight recorder but I wasn't able to find it so far.

## My question

How do you enable events from the `com.oracle.jdk.JavaMonitorEnter` type to be recorded by the Java Flight Recorder ?
Or I am missing something else and there is a better way to figure out how much blocking on synchronized blocks is done in a Java program ?

## My environment

I am using Oracle JDK version 1.8.0_191. The version of Java Mission Control I am using on my desktop is 6.0.0. Finally, the command I use to record my program's execution is the following:

```
java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=settings=profile,dumponexit=true,filename=test.jfr -classpath lib/*:src/ <my program with its arguments>
```

I should also add that connecting to the server directly with Java Mission Control is not an option (or is it?) as I am using an ssh rebound to actually connect to it ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A liitle more research on my own provided me with the answer.

The JavaMonitorEnter events (and other events that one would like to monitor) need to be specified in a flight recorder configuration file. In this situation, I was using the `profile` configuration which is provided along with the `default` configuration with the Oracle JDK.

I created my own configuration using Java Mission Control. [This blog](http://isuru-perera.blogspot.com/2016/03/specifying-custom-event-settings-file.html) was very helpful in presenting how to find the tool to create custom recording configurations in Java Mission Control.

I then exported my newly created configuration, uploaded it on my test environment and specified this configuration in my command (below the modified option only):

```
-XX:StartFlightRecording=settings=/home/<username>/Custom,<other options>...
```

**What my problem actually was**

Blocking recordings are activated in the flight recorder configurations provided by the Oracle JDK. However, for the blockings to actually be recorded, they need to last for more than a certain threshold (20ms in the `default` configuration, 10ms in the `profile` configuration).

In my application, individual blockings were shorter than this threshold, hence nothing appeared when I opened my recording in Java Mission Control.

My main source of confusion was the message stating that the "Java Blocking rule required events to be available ...". A more accurate description of my situation would be that *no blockings exceeding the configuration threshold were recorded*.

Comment: In Java 8, the event is called "java/monitor_enter", and should be enabled by default for both default and profile configurations.... So you should have seen it from the beginning.. (JMC 6 translates from the old Java 8 event ids (java/monitor_enter) into the new Java 9+ ids (JavaMonitorEnter) )

Comment: @Klara You are right, the java/monitor_enter event is activated in both `default` and `profile` configurations. Except that the threshold in these settings is too long for my application (10ms in the `profile` configuration, 20ms in the `default` configuration). 
In my application, the individual blockings I was trying to monitor were about 20 microseconds long so they would not show with these previous configurations.